# Как изменить содержимое одного QComboBox в зависимости от другого QComboBox в PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, gui, pyqt5, design

Всем доброго времени суток.

Пишу программу на python3 по расчету термодинамических свойств. Вот кусочек интерфейса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В первом combobox'е я у меня идет выбор веществ (коих 122). Далее  идет выбор параметров, и суть в том, что если, к примеру, значение в combobox стоит "**Давление (P)**", то в нижнем должны быть единицы измерения давление (Па, кПа, МПа, бар). Если стоит "Температура (К)", то, соответственно, ед.изм - это К, °C, °F. Реализовал я это так: создал два файла:

- testGUI.py - здесь весь GUI, созданный в Qt Designer
- CalcProp.py - здесь вся логика (классы и функции для расчетов)

В **CalcProp.py** я написал класс, содержащий функцию, возвращающую список параметров:

```
class ChooseParams():
   def paramList(self):
      P = 'Давление (P)'
      T = 'Температура (T)'
      D = 'Плотность (D)'
      V = 'Объем (V)'
      H = 'Энтальпия (h)'
      S = 'Энтропия (s)'
      Q = 'Степень сухости (x)'

      allParams = [P, T, D, V, H, S, Q]

      return allParams
```

Следом создал класс, содержащий функцию по выбору единиц измерения:

```
class ChooseUnitOfMeasurement():
    def unitOfMeasurement(self, parameter):

        #Давление
        Pa = 'Па'
        kPa = 'кПа'
        MPa = 'МПа'
        PressureUnitList = [Pa, kPa, MPa]

        #Температура
        kelvin = 'К'
        degC = '°C'
        degF = '°F'
        tempUnitList = [kelvin, degC, degF]

        #Энтальпия
        kJdivKg = 'кДж/кг'
        JdivKg = 'Дж/кг'
        enthalpyUnitList = [kJdivKg, JdivKg]

        #Энтропия
        kJdivKgKel = 'кДж/(кг-К)'
        JdivKgKel = 'Дж/(кг-К)'
        entropyUnitList = [kJdivKgKel, JdivKgKel]

        #Плотность
        kgDivMeter = 'кг/м^3'

        #Объем
        meterDivKg = 'м^3/кг'

        #Степень сухости
        vaporQuality = '--'


        if parameter == 'Давление (P)':
            return PressureUnitList
        elif parameter == 'Температура (T)':
            return tempUnitList
        elif parameter == 'Плотность (D)':
            return kgDivMeter
        elif parameter == 'Объем (V)':
            return meterDivKg
        elif parameter == 'Энтальпия (h)':
            return enthalpyUnitList
        elif parameter == 'Энтропия (s)':
            return entropyUnitList
        else:
            return vaporQuality
```

В **testGUI.py**

```
#Создание combobox для выбора первого параметра
self.comboBoxInputFirstParam = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBoxFirstParam)
#Добавляю в него параметры
self.comboBoxInputFirstParam.addItems(CalcProp.ChooseParams.paramList(self))

#Создание combobox для выбора Ед.Изм первого параметра
self.comboBoxInputFirstParamUnit = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBoxFirstParam)
#Получить содержимое первого combobox
firstParameter = self.comboBoxInputFirstParam.currentText()
#В зависимости от содержимого первого, добавить необходимый список/значение в combobox с Ед.Изм.
self.comboBoxInputFirstParamUnit.addItems(CalcProp.ChooseUnitOfMeasurement.unitOfMeasurement(self, firstParameter))
```

Аналогично все прописано и для второго параметра. И все работает, да вот только при запуске программы, когда я меня давление на, скажем, другую величину, то Ед.Изм не меняются. **И меня интересует, как менять содержимое одного combobox в зависимости от другого в режиме реального времени.**

Comment: Используйте сигнал `currentItemChanged` у вашего `comboBoxInputFirstParam`. Подлючите его к слоту, в котором заменяйте элементы вашего `comboBoxInputFirstParamUnit`.

Comment: @aleks.andr Слушай, уже второй час сижу и ломаю голову над этим. Пробовал `currentItemChanged ` вставлять куда только можно, но пока без результата. Можешь показать практически, как это будет выглядеть?

Answer (score 1):

Мне уже подсказали правильно решение. Поэтому оставлю его здесь

```
    [...]
    self.comboBoxInputFirstParam = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBoxFirstParam)
    self.comboBoxInputFirstParamUnit = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBoxFirstParam)
    self.comboBoxInputFirstParam.currentTextChanged.connect(self.onCurrentTextChanged)

    self.comboBoxInputFirstParam.addItems(CalcProp.ChooseParams().paramList())

def onCurrentTextChanged(self, text):
    self.comboBoxInputFirstParamUnit.clear()
    elements = CalcProp.ChooseUnitOfMeasurement().unitOfMeasurement(str(text))
    if isinstance(elements, list):
        self.comboBoxInputFirstParamUnit.addItems(elements)
    else:
        self.comboBoxInputFirstParamUnit.addItem(elements)
```